# rows_where argument not passed to pgr_nodenetwork

Tags: postgresql, geometry, geography, pgrouting

I am using the [`pgr_NodeNetwork`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_nodeNetwork.html) function of the `pgrouting` extension to process a table that contains linestring geometries (essentially, roads).

The syntax is the following :

```
select pgr_nodeNetwork(edge_table:='my_table', 
tolerance:=0.0001,
id:='id', 
the_geom:='the_geom',
table_ending:='noded',
rows_where:='id < 10',
outall:=false);
```

In particular, the argument `rows_where` is used to process only the rows for which the condition `rows_where` is true.

However, at the beginning of the execution, the following notice is raised:

```
NOTICE:     pgr_nodeNetwork('my_table', 0.0001, 'id', 'the_geom', 'noded', '<NULL>',  f)
```

You can see that **the notice doesn't take account of the `rows_where` argument that was passed to the function** (in my example, it was `'id < 10'`).

Moreover, it doesn't seem to be only a display problem in the notice itself, because the processing takes hours for a table with millions of rows, while it should be very fast if the condition `'id < 10'` had really been taken account of (because it would be a table with less than 10 rows).

On the other hand, if we explore the code of the function itself, it begins with:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sig.pgr_nodenetwork(
        edge_table text,
        tolerance double precision,
        id text DEFAULT 'id'::text,
        the_geom text DEFAULT 'the_geom'::text,
        table_ending text DEFAULT 'noded'::text,
        rows_where text DEFAULT ''::text,
        outall boolean DEFAULT false)

....

raise notice 'pgr_nodeNetwork(''%'', %, ''%'', ''%'', ''%'', ''%'',  %)',
    edge_table, tolerance, id,  the_geom, table_ending, rows_where, outall;
```

If you define another function with the same parameters and the same `RAISE NOTICE` instruction at the beginning, you will see that the notice raised by the function correctly reproduces the `rows_where` argument passed by the user.

Does anybody has an explanation as to why the `rows_where` argument seems to be utterly ignored by the pgr_nodeNetwork function, while defining a brand new function with the exact same code doesn't yield the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug (https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/1074). Although not fixed in the extension itself, I provided an alternative (custom) function (see link above).